# How to add new menu in admincp

Tags: phpfox

I have developed a new module in phpfox. and i want to add some menus in admincp for its settings. How to add New menu in admincp(phpfox) via admincp. i can't find the option for adding it. i can add the menu for frontend but not for admincp itself.
[image: AdminCP Menu In PhpFox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add menu for photo module from admin.

1. Goto **AdminCP** -> **Extensions** -> **Manage Modules**
2. Now select photo module and click on arrow in the left of it, where you find **edit** option
3. you find **Sub Menu:** option here.
4. Here you can add more menu to photo module.

Comment: How can i do with phpfox v4.x?